# How to replace different words from list found in string with specific word

Tags: c#, string, list, replace

How to replace different words from list found in string with specific word "x" :

```
string str = "how to replace different words from list found in string with specific word"; 

var valueList = new List<string> { "replace", "string", "specific", "found", "how", "word"};  

if (valueList.Any(str.Contains))   
{
   //...                       
}
```

if with if-statement I can do it one by one `str.Replace("replace", "x");` etc., but not sure how to properly get same result from listed values:

> x to x different words from list x in x with x x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq flavour:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "how to replace different words from list found in string with specific word"; 

        var valueList = new List<string> { "replace", "string", "specific", "found", "how", "word"};  

        var result = valueList.Aggregate(str, (current, c) => current.Replace(c, "x"));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BVJphf

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest you run some benchmark. I was just trying to come up with a Linq solution :-)